# Is there a generic debug print in OCaml or Core?

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have a user defined type like `type foo = string * string list`, if I want to insert print debug statements in my code to see what values it holds, what would be the fastest way to do it?

Seems like writing

`let (first, second) = foo in
printf "%s, %s" first (String.concat second)`

is a way too much work for a quick and dirty debug statement!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `ppx_sexp_conv`. If you're using `Core`, you don't have to do anything special. Loading `core` gives you all you need. Just add `[@@deriving sexp]` to all of your type definitions. For example:

```
# type foo = string * string list [@@deriving sexp];;
type foo = string * string list
val foo_of_sexp : Sexp.t -> foo = <fun>
val sexp_of_foo : foo -> Sexp.t = <fun>

# let foo = "hello", ["how"; "are"; "you"];;
val foo : string * string list = ("hello", ["how"; "are"; "you"])

# sexp_of_foo foo |> Sexp.to_string_hum;;
- : string = "(hello (how are you))"
```

It is also possible to generate the sexp function on the fly for types that weren't pre-defined. For example:

```
# [%sexp_of: string * int];;
- : string * int -> Sexp.t = <fun>

# [%sexp_of: string * int] ("foo", 42);;
- : Sexp.t = (foo 42)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `BatPervasives.dump` function in the "OCaml Batteries Included" library. Install with `opam install batteries`, then:

```
open Batteries

type 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

let t1 = Node(1, Leaf, Leaf)
let t2 = Node(2, t1, Leaf)
let t3 = Node(3, Leaf, t2)

let () = print_endline (dump t3)
```

Build with:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -linkpkg testdump.ml
```

or:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg batteries testdump.byte
```

Running it should produce:

```
(3, 0, (2, (1, 0, 0), 0))
```

As you can see, it's a somewhat stripped down representation compared to REPL output (it relies on the `Obj` module), but if you know the type, it's generally easy to figure out the value.

Answer (score 0):

This does not belong to Core but [deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving) is a library simplifying type-driven code generation and the function [show](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugin-show) does what you want, while printing in a format closer to JSON than SEXPs.

From the doc:

```ml
# type file = {
  name : string;
  perm : int     [@printer fun fmt -> fprintf fmt "0o%03o"];
} [@@deriving show];;
# show_file { name = "dir"; perm = 0o755 };;
- : string = "{ name = \"dir\"; perm = 0o755 }"
```